# Having Access to a file inside Package of Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, namespaces, composer-php, autoload

I am developing a package for Laravel 4, inside that I have created a file which should be accessible inside the application which installs my package

The path to the file is this

```
 myPackage-
     |--src
         |--MyNamepace
               |--MyPackage
               |    |--libs
               |         |--myFile.php 
               |-myPackageServiceProvider
```

and inside my composer.json file I have the following:

```
 "autoload": {

    "classmap": [
        "src/controllers",
        "src/views",
        "src/models",
        "src/database/migrations"
    ],
    "psr-0": {
        "MyNamespace\\MyPackage": "src/"
    }
```

myFile.php has the following namespace and content:

```
<?php namespace MyNamespace\MyPackage\libs;


   return [
     //some data here
   ];
```

Question:

where am I possibly making mistake that the path to this file is not included in the `autoload_classmap.php` file of the application, and I don't have access to it inside the application which installs the package?

Comment: The key to this problem is the psr-0 namespace declaration in your `composer.json` file. I'm afraid I don't know enough about it to answer the question definitively, so you should check out [the docs for composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload).

Comment: What's inside `myFile.php`? is the namespace set correctly?

Comment: @lukasgeiter I edited the question please check it again

Comment: Apparently your file doesn't contain a class so obviously it's not included in `autoload_CLASSmap.php`... Is it some kind of config file?

Comment: @lukasgeiter I just realized where I was making mistake, yes it's a config file

Answer (score 1):

Since your file doesn't contain a class it won't be autoloaded and obviously isn't included in `autoload_CLASSmap.php`.

If your developing a package for Laravel only you can simple use the way Laravel handles config files:

1. Place the file in `myPackage/src/config/myFile.php`
2. Access the config by `Config::get('myPackage::myFile.foo`)` (it works the same as the normal Laravel config values)

[More information on package development for Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/packages)

You can also just "load" the file using `require`. And even better, there's `File::getRequire()` you can use:

```
$config = File::getRequire('path/to/file.php');
```